# leveneTest between 2-levels of 3-level factor?

Tags: r

What I have done so far:

I have a data.frame `results` with response `Fail`, and three factors `PREP`, `CLEAN` & `ADHES`.
`ADHES` has 3 levels: `Crest`    `Cryst`     `Poly`

I calculated the variances:

```
sigma..k=tapply(Fail,ADHES,var)
print(sqrt(sigma..k)):

Crest    Cryst     Poly 
17.56668 41.64679 39.42669
```

then used `leveneTest` to test for constance of variance:

```
print(leveneTest(Fail~ADHES))

Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
      Df F value  Pr(>F)  
group  2   3.929 0.02588 *
      51
```

The Question:
Now I want to use Levene's to test between only the `Cryst` & `Poly` levels of the factor `ADHES`, but I can't work out the syntax to do this in R.

Comment: subset you data previously to the analysis? could you provide some data?

Comment: Thanks LyzandeR, I'm also very new to stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint @PauloCardoso gave me I worked it out:

```
    leveneTest(subset(results,ADHES == 'Cryst' | ADHES == 'Poly')[,5],
subset(results,ADHES == 'Cryst' | ADHES == 'Poly')[,3])
```

('Fail' & 'ADHES' are columns 5 & 3 respectively in my data.frame 'results')

Obrigadinho!

Comment: Inglaterra, e agora IST! e tu?

Comment: Lisboa. boa sorte com o R!